# How NON Persistent XSS Attacks can be controlled by Hackers?

Tags: php, html, xss

Say i have a following php code.

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
echo "Welcome $name<br>";
echo "<a href="http://xssattackexamples.com/">Click to Download</a>";
?>
```

Now the attacker will craft an URL as follows and send it to the victim:

```
index.php?name=guest<script>alert('attacked')</script>
```

This will just do an alert to the particular user only right ? there is no harm to other users right ?

**And is there any similar kind of NON Persistent XSS attack that can change the coarse of website ?**

Comment: actually you should stop it from alerting ! that is your job

Comment: your question is not clear you want to stop the XSS OR you want the XSS to affect only the targeted user ?

Comment: @AncientGeek : I just wanted to understand the impact of XSS

Comment: it could be extremely painful [ask myspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samy_%28computer_worm%29)

Comment: @AncientGeek : I am also looking for an severe example which can cause  the damage to the system...